# ¿Cómo capturar el response de una API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

El caso es el siguiente, necesito capturar el response de una `API`, el `Request` esta hecho con `Axios` y `Vuex`, lo que necesito hacer es guardar el response que me genera la `API` cuando el Usuario se loggea, al guardar el response debo enviarlo al `localStorage` para que la información del usuario quede almacenada pero hasta ahora lo que he intentado no funciona, el `Request` es el siguiente:

```
    import Vue from 'vue'
    import Vuex from 'vuex'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import router from './router';

    Vue.use(Vuex)

    export default new Vuex.Store({

      state: { // Estado
        accessToken: null,
        loggingIn: false,
        loginError: null
      },

      mutations: { 

        loginStart: state => state.loggingIn = true,
        loginStop: (state, errorMessage) => {
          state.loggingIn = false;
          state.loginError = errorMessage;
        },
        updateAccessToken: (state, accessToken) => {
          state.accessToken = accessToken;
        },
        logout: (state) => {
          state.accessToken = null;
        }
      },
      actions: {


        doLogin({ commit }, loginData) {
          commit('loginStart');

          axios.post('https://marketing- 
           sitimaps.appspot.com/user/Login/', {
            ...loginData,

          })
          .then(response => {
            localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.token);
            commit('loginStop', null);
            commit('updateAccessToken', response.data.token);
            router.push('/users');
          })
          .catch(error => {
            commit('loginStop', error.response.data.error);
            commit('updateAccessToken', null);
          })
        },
        fetchAccessToken({ commit }) {
          commit('updateAccessToken', localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));                                                                      
        },
        logout({ commit }) {
          localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
          commit('logout');
          router.push('/login');
        }
      }
    })


   // Funcion que intenta almacenar el response..

    let response = localStorage.setItem('accessToken', response.data.token);
     for (let i in response.length) {        
         console.log(response);

    }
```

Hasta ahora el `request` funciona correctamente, lo que necesito es almacenar el response en un objeto, para después poder iterar en el por medio de ciclos `for`.

Answer (score 0):

en localStorage sólo puedes almacenar un string en una clave única. [Aquí la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem).

Lo que deberías hacer es convertir el contenido de la respuesta en string, de lo contrario cuando consultes en el localStorage tendrás algo como `"[object Object]"`, para ello se puede usar el método JSON.stringify() y cuando lo vayas a consultar hacer el procedimiento contrario con el método JSON.parse(), así:

```
localStorage.setItem('respuesta', JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

y cuando lo vayas a recuperar

```
var respuestaQueGuarde = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('respuesta'));
```

Espero que te sirva.